# Remove unwanted strings and characters in a multi line textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have this two paragraph as sample in in a multiline textbox.

Now I want to remove this line(REF: Miller, p. 25 my sample(sentences is my sample is my sample)>> Week 2) of each paragraph.

1. sample sentences is my sample is my sample

sample sentences is my sample is my sample

sample sentences is my sample is my sample.

REF: Miller, p. 25 my sample(sentences is my sample is my sample)>> Week 2"

2. sample sentences is my sample is my sample.

sample sentences is my sample is my sample

REF: Miller, p. 25 my sample(sentences is my sample is my sample)>> Week 2

```
Dim s As String = textcon.Text 
Dim r As String = s.Replace("<<" & s.Split("<<")(s.Split("<<").Length - 1), String.Empty) 
TextBox2.Text = r
```

i have tried this code but it is only removing the last line in the 2nd paragraph.

any ideas.

Comment: Maybe you can use the string split and join methods. Look up their docs.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a coding service and you are expected to show some effort in solving your own problem.  You didnt even ask a question, just spat out some reqs and sample

Comment: Dim s As String = textcon.Text
        Dim r As String = s.Replace("<<" & s.Split("<<")(s.Split("<<").Length - 1), String.Empty)
        TextBox2.Text = r      i have tried this code but it is only removing the last line in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: my bad.........

Comment: so `Dim r As String = s.Replace("REF: Miller, p. 25 my sample(sentences is my sample is my sample)>> Week 2", "")` is no good?